# How can I access the changed variable from another class

Tags: python, class, object, variables, self

I want to print(read or use) the changing variable self.tt in B().check() while class A is changing self.tt, is it any way to do it or other better solution to achieve the task?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tt = 0

    def change_tt(self):
        for i in range(100000000):
            self.tt += 1
            sleep(1)


class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = A.tt

    def check(self):
        while True:
            print(self.x)


a = A()
b = B()

x1 = threading.Thread(target=A.change_tt)
x2 = threading.Thread(target=B.check)

x1.start()
x2.start()
```

```
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'tt'
```

Comment: `...(target=A.change_tt)` this method call is wrong: it requires that `change_tt` to be a class method, which is not the case. try without `Thread`-stuffs and you will get the same error

Comment: Threads are fine here. Use `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here. The biggest issue is that you can't access an instance attribute from the class. A secondary issue is that integers are immutable.

Here is some code that should fix both:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tt = 0

    def change_tt(self):
        for i in range(100000000):
            self.tt += 1
            sleep(1)


class B():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def check(self):
        while True:
            print(self.a.tt)


a = A()
b = B(a)

x1 = threading.Thread(target=a.change_tt)
x2 = threading.Thread(target=b.check)

x1.start()
x2.start()
```

Notice that the code of class `A` remains unchanged. However, it's important to understand that it is being used differently. `A` is the class object. It has attributes that are functions, but no integers. When you create instance `a`, the functions become methods when you access them with the `.` operator. `a` also has an attribute `tt`.

A thread target should be a no-arg callable. The functions `A.change_tt` and `B.check` both require a single positional argument, `self`. However, the bound methods `a.change_tt` and `b.check` are no-arg callables. The process of binding a function to an instance with the `.` operator creates a wrapper that passes in `self` automatically.

When you do `self.tt += 1`, the object that is the previous value of `tt` is unbound from `tt` and possibly garbage collected. Integers are immutable, which means that what really happens here is `self.tt = self.tt + 1`. That means that the statement `self.x = A.tt` in `B.__init__` is unreasonable even if `tt` existed in `A`. `x` would be a reference to the object that is the initial value of `tt`, and would keep referring to that object even as `tt` changed to the incremented version.

An instance of `B` needs to know about the object that `A.tt` refers to currently. One way to do that is to pass a reference to `B.__init__`. That's why we define `__init__(self, a)`, and invoke `B` as `B(a)` to get an instance that refers to `a`.

Comment: Thank you so much, may I ask why the a inside def __init__(self, a) but not B(a) or B(A)?

Comment: @tung. I've updated my answer. I'm not really sure what your question means. `b = B(a)` is how we do the initialization.